# Codeigniter echo result in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I call the result in my view?

`print_r` gives me `Array ( [0] => 2017-09-25 [1] => 2017-09-27 )`

In my view file

`echo $coachact->session_date` gives me `"non-object"`

`echo $session_date` gives me `"undefined variable"`

Controller code

```
public function editview($user_fname)
{
    $returnData = array();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->User_model->checkIfLoggedIn();

    $this->load->view('incf/header');
    $this->load->view('schedulef/sced_tools');

    $this->load->model('Schedule_model');
    $coachact = $this->Schedule_model->get($user_fname);
    if(!empty($coachact)){
        $returnData['coachact'] = $coachact;
        $returnData['user_fname'] = $user_fname;      
    }
    $this->load->view('schedulef/Schedule_manage',$returnData);
    //print_r($coachact);exit();
}
```

Model

```
public function get($user_fname)
{
    $returnArray = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE user_fname = ?", ['user_fname' => $user_fname]);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        array_push($returnArray, $row->session_date);
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller code make change like this :

```
public function editview($user_fname)
{
    $returnData = array();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->User_model->checkIfLoggedIn();

    $this->load->view('incf/header');
    $this->load->view('schedulef/sced_tools');

    $this->load->model('Schedule_model');
    $coachact = $this->Schedule_model->get($user_fname);
    if(!empty($coachact)){
        $returnData['coachact'] = $coachact;
        $returnData['user_fname'] = $user_fname;        
    }
    $this->load->view('schedulef/Schedule_manage',$returnData);

}
```

And in the view file directly access the value as

`<?php echo $coachact; ?>`

And

`<?php echo $user_fname; ?>`

And the output you are getting in the upper left corner is due to the `echo` statement in the model file.

Here is your Modal Code :

```
public function get($user_fname)
    {
        $returnArray['sesdate'] = array();
        $query       = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE user_fname = ?", ['user_fname' => $user_fname]);

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {                  
          $sesdate = strtotime($row->session_date);
          $sesdate = date("Fj Y",$sesdate);
          array_push($returnArray['sesdate'], $sesdate);
        }   
        return $returnArray;
    }
```

And since there is more than one result you have to use a loop in the view file.

Answer (score 1):

> In my view file echo $coachact->session_date gives me "non-object"
>   echo $session_date gives me "undefined variable"

As you can see below, in your code you are sending array to view

```
$coachact = $this->Schedule_model->get($user_fname);
if(!empty($coachact)){
    $returnData['coachact'] = $coachact;
    $returnData['user_fname'] = $user_fname;      
}
$this->load->view('schedulef/Schedule_manage',$returnData);
```

So in your view you will have, 2 variables namely:

```
$coachact 
$user_fname
```

To print the contents of `$user_fname`, you just have to

echo `$user_fname;`

To view contents of `$coachact` array you have access like below

```
echo $coachact[0];  // gives first element
```

To loop through results

```
<?php foreach($coachact as $key => $value): ?>
         <p><?php echo $key. '=>' . $value;?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```